# Update publish profile defaults

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

5 years or so ago, I created a small site on Azure for a one-off side project. I created a publish profile for the site, pushed it out there, and forgot about it. The site has since been taken down, and the information in that profile is no longer useful.

However, Azure still has it somewhere, tied to my Microsoft ID, and set as the default option whenever I create new resources. If, for example, I create a new App Service called MyNewApp within my employers subscription, the FTP/deployment username will be "MyNewApp\Oldpersonalprojectuser". I can update this to something more appropriate after the resource is created, but I have to remember do it for every resource, every time.

How can I update or remove this default?

Comment: The only option I've found so far is Reseting the publish profile through PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/reset-azurermwebapppublishingprofile?view=azurermps-3.8.0 but I'm not sure if it will produce what you're expecting...

Comment: Looks like that's just the cmdlet equivalent to resetting the profile for a specific app in the portal, which I've done many times. I'll give it a try in the morning though, maybe it does something the portal doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If, for example, I create a new App Service called MyNewApp within my employers subscription, the FTP/deployment username will be "MyNewApp\Oldpersonalprojectuser". I can update this to something more appropriate after the resource is created, but I have to remember do it for every resource, every time.

As far as I know, Azure App Service supports two types of credentials for local Git deployment and FTP/S deployment.

1.User-level credentials: one set of credentials for the entire Azure account. It can be used to deploy to App Service for any app, in any subscription, that the Azure account has permission to access. These are the default credentials set that you configure in App Services >  > Deployment credentials. This is also the default set that's surfaced in the portal GUI.

I guess " FTP/deployment username " is user-level credentials, this credentials for the entire Azure account. You will find all your web application ftp user is 
"MyNewApp\Oldpersonalprojectuser". This credentials is used to access all your web application.

You could find it in the overview like below:
[image]

So I don't suggest you change the value after each web application deployed.
All your  all your resources' FTP/deployment username will changed.

If you want to change this value, you could click your app service's Deployment credentials button like below:
[image]

2.App-level credentials: one set of credentials for each app. It can be used to deploy to that app only. The credentials for each app is generated automatically at app creation, and is found in the app's publish profile. You cannot manually configure the credentials, but you can reset them for an app anytime.

If you want to reset App-level credentials, you could try click the reset publish profile button in the overview.

Like below:
[image]

More details, you could refer to below article:
[Configure deployment credentials for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deployment-credentials)

Comment: Reading comprehension fail, I didn't realize that credential was actually shared across all instances. I had tried the "reset" option repeatedly, but never actually just edited the username from that section. Thanks!